# Desenhar imagem utilizando css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Gostaria de saber se teria como desenha a imagem abaixo utilizando somente css? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de criar um botão deste jeito
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode utilizar `:after` e `:before` pra "criar" elementos vinculados com o elemento pai

Comment: É possível... Só acredito que não terá alguém disposto a fazer isso por ti.

Comment: "desenha" é diferente de "desenhar".. de qualquer forma, veja esse link: http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/VbgKW/

Comment: Relacionada: [Como fazer essa flecha em CSS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41592/como-fazer-essa-flecha-em-css)

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando os pseudo-elementos `:after` e `:before`:

Na sua necessidade talvez seja necessário adaptar o código alterando os valores de `top`, `left` e `rigth` até atingir o efeito que deseja

```css
div{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top:40px;
  left:50px;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px 130px 0 130px;
  border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  right: 220px;
  top: -80px;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  left: 20px;
  top: -130px;
}

button{
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
left: 0px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);

  border-radius: 70px;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<br/>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Teria como colocar este desenho embaixo de um botão preto para dar a impressão que esta seta pertence ao botão? Estou tentando porém ainda não consegui.

Comment: Como assim? Lembrando que você não está "desenhando" e sim estilizando elementos do `HTML`, poste um exemplo do código do seu botão e explique melhor qual a sua necessidade

Comment: Atualizei a minha pergunta com a imagem de como gostaria do botão

Answer (score 3):

É possível sim, usando HTML e CSS, aqui tem um gerador para você ter uma ideia de como se faz = http://www.samuelrossille.com/css-shape/#1142AAy15z-15z-19z29z0

Sempre vai ter que ter pelo menos uma tag HTML, porque CSS é folha de estilo, ai o desenho é feito em cima do HTML.